# How can I combine 4 columns of data into a single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL 2008 Im trying to combine the data from 4 columns into a single column. I have searched and tried several different things but none have worked. My latest attempt has been :

```
SELECT [2012 Notes] + [2012 STEPS TAKEN TO REMEDY ISSUES] + [2013 NOTES] + [2013 STEPS TAKEN TO REMEDY ISSUES] AS 'ConcatNotes'
FROM ECRSurvey

UPDATE ECRSurvey Set UserNotes = 'ConcatNotes'
```

This does not work though. Can someone tell me the proper way to do this? Im basically trying to take 4 columns and trying to combine that data into the UserNotes field.

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: What is ECRSurvey table strtucture? Does [2012 Notes] - the name column?

Comment: You probably have to use a conversion function. Check the examples here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work - you probably have some NULLS.

try

```
SELECT ISNULL([2012 Notes],'') + ISNULL([2012 STEPS TAKEN TO REMEDY ISSUES],'') + ISNULL([2013 NOTES],'') + ISNULL([2013 STEPS TAKEN TO REMEDY ISSUES],'') AS 'ConcatNotes'
FROM ECRSurvey
```

or to update

```
UPDATE ECRSurvey Set UserNotes = ISNULL([2012 Notes],'') + ISNULL([2012 STEPS TAKEN TO REMEDY ISSUES],'') + ISNULL([2013 NOTES],'') + ISNULL([2013 STEPS TAKEN TO REMEDY ISSUES],'')
```

Comment: Your ISNULL checks need the 2nd parameter

Comment: THIS DID IT!!! I used the update query and it worked liked a charm. Thank you so much. That was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

If any of those columns contain NULLs, the result will be NULL.  You'll want to coalesce or isnull checks on the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following query:

```
Update ECRSurvey
set UserNotes =[2012 Notes] + [2012 STEPS TAKEN TO REMEDY ISSUES] + [2013 NOTES] + [2013 STEPS TAKEN TO REMEDY ISSUES]
```